# Proof by contradiction. Discrete question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I want to prove the following question by contradiction.

> Prove that if $x$ is an integer and $3x+2$ is even, then $x$ is even.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Suppose that $3x+2$ is even and $x$ is odd, then $3x$ is odd, and so $3x + 2$should be odd, but it is even, contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

1. Let us assume that $x$ is an odd integer.
2. Then $3x$ would be odd, since two odd integers multiplied together produce an odd product.
3. After this, $3x + 2$ will be odd since an odd integer plus an even integer is odd.
4. **But $3x + 2$ is required to be even.** This is a contradiction, and so **$x$ can not be odd in the first place, so $x$ MUST be even.**

*Q.E.D.*

Comment: Don't you have to proof why x must be even at the end ? I am a little confused :(

Comment: @AliAziz $x$ is required to be either even or odd. There is no "in between" choice.